# Speed of dereferencing class properties in fortran

Tags: performance, methods, properties, fortran, dereference

I expect answer like ***don't worry, compiler will take care of that*** but I wan't to be sure.

When I make some method in some custom type/class in fortran, is there any performance hit due to referencing/dereferencing fields of the object like `this%a(i) = this%b(i) + this%c(i)` in comparison to just working with arrays like `a(i) = b(i) + c(i)`

**more complex example:**

for example I have this function which should interpolate a value on 3D grid which is really performance critical (it would be called inside a triple loop over an other 3D array). So I'm thinking if it is better ( for performance) to make is using a method of the class, or rather make a normal subroutine which takes the array as an argument.

```
type grid3D                                         ! 3D grid maps of observables
  real,    dimension (3) :: Rmin, Rmax, Rspan, step ! grid size and spacing (x,y,z)
  integer, dimension (3) :: N                       ! dimension in x,y,z
  real, dimension (3,:, :, :), allocatable :: f     ! array storing values of othe observable
  contains
    procedure :: interpolate => grid3D_interpolate
end type grid3D

function grid3D_interpolate(this, R ) result(ff)
 implicit none
  ! variables
  class (grid3D) :: this
  real, dimension (3), intent (in)   :: R
  real :: ff
  integer ix0,iy0,iz0
  integer ix1,iy1,iz1
  real dx,dy,dz
  real mx,my,mz
  ! function body
  ix0 = int( (R(1)/this%step(1)) + fastFloorOffset ) - fastFloorOffset
  iy0 = int( (R(2)/this%step(2)) + fastFloorOffset ) - fastFloorOffset
  iz0 = int( (R(3)/this%step(3)) + fastFloorOffset ) - fastFloorOffset
  dx = R(1) - x0*this%step(1)
  dy = R(2) - y0*this%step(2)
  dz = R(3) - z0*this%step(3)
  ix0 = modulo( x0   , this%N(1) )+1
  iy0 = modulo( y0   , this%N(2) )+1
  iz0 = modulo( z0   , this%N(3) )+1
  ix1 = modulo( x0+1 , this%N(1) )+1
  iy1 = modulo( y0+1 , this%N(2) )+1
  iz1 = modulo( z0+1 , this%N(3) )+1
  mx=1.0-dx
  my=1.0-dy
  mz=1.0-dz
  ff =    mz*(my*(mx*this%f(ix0,iy0,iz0)     &
                 +dx*this%f(ix1,iy0,iz0))    &
             +dy*(mx*this%f(ix0,iy1,iz0)     &
                 +dx*this%f(ix1,iy1,iz0)))   &
         +dz*(my*(mx*this%f(ix0,iy0,iz1)     &
                 +dx*this%f(ix1,iy0,iz1))    &
             +dy*(mx*this%f(ix0,iy1,iz1)     &
                 +dx*this%f(ix1,iy1,iz1)))
  end if
end function grid3D_interpolate

end module T_grid3Dvec
```

Comment: If you care about such issues why don't you make some experiments and gather some data ?  If you want to be sure get some evidence, don't rely on the assertions of strangers.

Comment: partially you are right, but by asking I can get also some broader understanding or recommendation rather than just observation.

Comment: I doubt there could be a difference, you are just dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: Well, yes, but by (only) asking you show little commitment to developing the understanding you seek.  Your question would be much stronger if you had made the measurements first, then solicited other input.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would be better to test how is it in my particular case any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not really.**

- As long as your code structure is quite clear (to the compiler), it can optimize that away quite easily.
- Once your OOP structures get too complicated, or the level of dereferencing gets too large, you might get some improvement out of a manual dereferencing scheme. (I use that quite a lot, although usually to keep my code human-readable. But I had a little improvement here once, but with a code using >5 levels of dereferencing. )

Here is some example:

```
module vec_mod
  implicit none

  type t_vector
    real :: x = 0.
    real :: y = 0.
    real :: z = 0.
  end type

  type t_group
    type(t_vector),allocatable :: vecs(:)
  end type

contains

  subroutine sum_vec( vecs, res )
    implicit none
    type(t_vector),intent(in)   :: vecs(:)
    type(t_vector),intent(out)  :: res
    integer                     :: i

    res%x = 0. ; res%y = 0. ; res%z = 0.

    do i=1,size(vecs)
      res%x = res%x + vecs(i)%x
      res%y = res%y + vecs(i)%y
      res%z = res%z + vecs(i)%z
    enddo
  end subroutine

  subroutine sum_vec_ptr( vecs, res )
    implicit none
    type(t_vector),intent(in),target   :: vecs(:)
    type(t_vector),intent(out)         :: res
    integer                            :: i
    type(t_vector),pointer             :: curVec

    res%x = 0. ; res%y = 0. ; res%z = 0.

    do i=1,size(vecs)
      curVec => vecs(i)
      res%x = res%x + curVec%x
      res%y = res%y + curVec%y
      res%z = res%z + curVec%z
    enddo
  end subroutine

  subroutine sum_vecGrp( vecGrp, res )
    implicit none
    type(t_group),intent(in)    :: vecGrp
    type(t_vector),intent(out)  :: res
    integer                     :: i

    res%x = 0. ; res%y = 0. ; res%z = 0.

    do i=1,size(vecGrp%vecs)
      res%x = res%x + vecGrp%vecs(i)%x
      res%y = res%y + vecGrp%vecs(i)%y
      res%z = res%z + vecGrp%vecs(i)%z
    enddo
  end subroutine

  subroutine sum_vecGrp_ptr( vecGrp, res )
    implicit none
    type(t_group),intent(in),target    :: vecGrp
    type(t_vector),intent(out)         :: res
    integer                            :: i
    type(t_vector),pointer             :: curVec, vecs(:)

    res%x = 0. ; res%y = 0. ; res%z = 0.

    vecs => vecGrp%vecs
    do i=1,size(vecs)
      curVec => vecs(i)
      res%x = res%x + curVec%x
      res%y = res%y + curVec%y
      res%z = res%z + curVec%z
    enddo
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use omp_lib
  use vec_mod
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env
  implicit none
  type(t_vector),allocatable :: vecs(:)
  type(t_vector)             :: res
  type(t_group)              :: vecGrp
  integer,parameter          :: N=100000000
  integer                    :: i, stat
  real(REAL64)               :: t1, t2

  allocate( vecs(N), vecGrp%vecs(N), stat=stat )
  if (stat /= 0) stop 'Cannot allocate memory'

  do i=1,N
    call random_number(vecs(i)%x)
    call random_number(vecs(i)%y)
    call random_number(vecs(i)%z)
  enddo

  print *,''
  print *,'1 Level'
  t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  call sum_vec( vecs, res )
  print *,res
  t2 = omp_get_wtime()
  print *,'Normal  [s]:', t2-t1

  t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  call sum_vec_ptr( vecs, res )
  print *,res
  t2 = omp_get_wtime()
  print *,'Pointer [s]:', t2-t1

  print *,''
  print *,'2 Levels'
  vecGrp%vecs = vecs

  t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  call sum_vecGrp( vecGrp, res )
  print *,res
  t2 = omp_get_wtime()
  print *,'Normal  [s]:', t2-t1

  t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  call sum_vecGrp_ptr( vecGrp, res )
  print *,res
  t2 = omp_get_wtime()
  print *,'Pointer [s]:', t2-t1

end program
```

Compiled with default options (`gfortran test.F90 -fopenmp`), three is a slight benefit from manually dereferencing, especially for two levels of dereferencing:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out 

 1 Level
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Normal  [s]:  0.69216769299237058     
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Pointer [s]:  0.67321390099823475     

 2 Levels
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Normal  [s]:  0.84902219301147852     
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Pointer [s]:  0.71247501399193425
```

Once you turn on optimization (`gfortran test.F90 -fopenmp -O3`), you can see that the compiler actually does a better job automatically:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out 

 1 Level
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Normal  [s]:  0.13888958499592263     
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Pointer [s]:  0.19099253200693056     

 2 Levels
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Normal  [s]:  0.13436777899914887     
   16777216.0       16777216.0       16777216.0    
 Pointer [s]:  0.21104205500159878
```

Comment: oh, interestion. Have you idea why the "pointer" version is slower than "normal" when  with `-O3` optimization flag?

Comment: Just guessing: (a) the loop contains very little operations, so the association might have a stronger impact (b) maybe the compiler cannot do all optimizations with pointers it could do with regular variables (c) maybe the `target` specifier inhibits some optimizations. It's hard to say w/o looking into how the optimizations actually are performed...